In Avalonia,how to set the position of the control
Thanks all
My requirements are as follows:
In a form, there is a control that can dynamically set its position, similar to absolute positioning in HTML
First of all, what I don't quite understand is where this control should be placed. The AI's answer to me is like this, and I always feel a bit strange
<Canvas>
    <Button Content="Move Me" Canvas. Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"/>
</Canvas>

Secondly, I want to set the position of the control through code, but I found that the position related properties are read-only. I know it's possible to do it through binding, but isn't it possible to control it directly through code without binding?

Can you explain what is the difference betweeen binding and “through code without binding” to you? You still change it via code and end result is the same. One is just the correct way and there’s not really any need to try to do it otherwise.

I doubt Canvas is the right container, you may provide AI with 0 requirements. Otherwise Canvas obviously should occupy all place, where its children (e.g. Button) will appear. It could be a whole window, part of UserControl, etc.. we don't know. To set value of attached property from the code: buttonInstance.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 0). "position related properties" is a mystery, unless you show what you mean with .. code?

thanks @SamiKuhmonen
Actually, there's no particular reason why I don't use bingding. It's just that in my scenario, many of the controls are dynamically obtained. If the position can be directly set, it would be more convenient

thanks @Sinatr
My goal is to create a floating form that doesn't take up space on the form, whether it's displayed or not. It floats on the top layer, just like the absolute positioning in HTML.
The advice given by AI is indeed feasible, and the existence of Canvas has no impact on other controls. I'm actually quite confused about this. I think Canvas should also take up space

Your AI's suggestion is accurate in this case, but its fault is that it is giving you the code without explanation of it.
The Canvas is the correct panel to use for coordinate based layout.
Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top are called attached properties. Attached properties allow you to manipulate how an object will behave within its parent.  However, to set these in code, you have to use the static methods in the parent, this can be a little counterintuitive since in XAML you set the properties on the child.
To do this without binding you need to have an instance of the child.  The easiest way to do this is to give it a name (assuming you are working in code behind).
<Canvas>
    <Button Name="myButton" Content="Move Me"/>
</Canvas>

Canvas.SetLeft(myButton, 0D);
Canvas.SetTop(myButton, 0D);


thanks @Tarazed
The code can be used, thank you
However, I am puzzled as to why this design is necessary. Why can't we directly set the properties on the instance? MyCanvas.Left=10 is very intuitive

foo.Bar = value is a syntax to call Bar property setter on foo instance. Attached properties are not normal properties and their syntax is different, because they need one more parameter (one is instance to attach property and another is property owner): foo.SetValue(bar, value) or SomeType.SetBar(foo, value).  To better understand concept it's worth to refer wpf topics, avalonia help is not extensive enough.

I agree, WPF help can be applicable to Avalonia, just be aware certain topics will be completely foreign.  Styles especially, but also if you delve into authoring controls, the AvaloniaProperty have a lot different signature than the WPF DependencyProperty.  There are other subtle differences as well.  All that said, for the most part, you will find WPF documentation can be very close to Avalonia despite those differences.
